# Trouble using $attrs in directives controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

My directive has an attribute `id-model` that is used to pass an array to the directive. The directives controller should execute a function using that array as an argument. I can access the attribute in my controller and log the array but my function never runs and I'm not sure why.

If I don't use the attribute and change `placesFact.getDetails(idModel)` to `placesFact.getDetails($scope.model)` everything works fine but I want there to be more flexibility with the directive.

***Update:**
To clarify on the `placesFact.getDetails()` method, It looks up google place info with a place id and returns the results as a promise. It has been tested and works fine.

**Directive**

```
.directive('gPlaces', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: '@',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.tempUrl = attrs.tempUrl;
    },
    controller: function($scope, $attrs, placesFact) {
      var idModel = $attrs.idModel;

      $attrs.$observe('idModel', function(value) {
        idModel = value;
        console.log(idModel);  // This logs the array
        placesFact.getDetails(idModel).then(function(results) {
          console.log(results);  // This logs nothing
          $scope.places = results;
        });
      });
    },
    template: '<div ng-include="tempUrl"></div>'
  }
})
```

**Controller**

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('PlacesCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.model = [
        'ChIJR4dOl_hYwokRApSCaQiBidk',
        'ChIJv-Ghof5YwokRMtWLEV12hJI',
        'ChIJjyX2GqRZwokRT-gdcGoPuSI',
        'ChIJqSurReFYwokRec7JFACToas',
        'ChIJn8dCo-NYwokRC_4nRUQWbNE',
        'ChIJszmN0-JYwokRk-XCDbO6X_Y',
        'ChIJt4TrE_1YwokRVedrKxaqYoo',
        'ChIJiW0WvwJZwokRIWyzCvo3o5k',
        'ChIJsS1xLQJZwokRGfXJPMwXA1A',
        'ChIJI5xCX6NZwokR3jdSQwsw2DI',
        'ChIJuVE5aLtZwokR-K75OxUEtzI',
        'ChIJ7R4tgLtZwokRM8thlhlzE2o',
        'ChIJxbWTG_pYwokRPgtFVKi-Cuc',
        'ChIJKZVnwFVYwokRgDw_sxw3NCo',
        'ChIJw_JUgvhYwokR91EMxVDhB8M',
        'ChIJZ3oXOVZYwokRNnAXaDRKAzg',
        'ChIJP9idxlZYwokRLH-I1mNfzYQ',
        'ChIJndGJ5FNYwokRricJvhT0t1s',
        'ChIJhZ0Sn1ZYwokRRA1MZJZHrHA',
        'ChIJhTdv51NYwokR7V105uVzf8g',
        'ChIJvfVwDFJYwokRtWobbwOMEVM',
        'ChIJpY9Tg01YwokRCr_aQpDrqgk',
        'ChIJ-fRuLFdYwokR0KKQ6Av_WhQ',
        'ChIJh-DIsE1YwokRhuFrdM1ge5E'
    ];    
});
```

**View**

```
<g-places temp-url="pages/places/multiTemp.html" id-model={{model}}></g-places>
```

Comment: You shouldn't rely on `var idModel = $attrs.idModel` because the attribute is not interpolated at the moment when controller runs. If it works and $attrs.$observe doesn't, you're doing something wrong, nobody except you knows how `placesFact.getDetails` works. Btw, `scope: '@'` syntax is wrong, too.

Comment: what is the implementation of `getDetails`? if it is `$resource`, you need to use `placesFact.getDetails(idModel).$promise.then(function(results) {`

Comment: @estus @Kami I edited the question to clarify on the `placesFact.getDetails` This is my first attempt at a directive so forgive me if I am off on some things. What should the `scope: '@'` syntax be, from what I was reading I thought that was appropriate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As estus mentioned in the comments, my `scope: '@'` syntax was wrong and was the root of the problem. This is my first directive so a little trial and error and a lot of reading lead me to figure out what to do though.

Here is how the directive looks now that it is working.

```
.directive('gPlaces', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      idModel: '=',
      tempUrl: '@'
    },
    controller: function($scope, placesFact) {

      placesFact.getDetails($scope.idModel).then(function(results) {
        $scope.places = results;
      });
    },
    template: '<div ng-include="tempUrl"></div>'
  }
})
```